# Linking to files in Expression Engine templates (path name problems)

Tags: expressionengine

Hey, new to expression engine - loving it, but having difficulties with linking to external files. I know this differs from server to server, but at present I see no end to these woes and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Server issues of any shade tend to give me panic attacks. They are my kryptonite.

1) Expression Engine 2.1 is installed in a subfolder of our site (www.website.com/client)

2) I have made a template group and set it up to save as files, and uploaded a logo within a subfolder (system/expressionengine/templates/default_site/site.group/images/logo.jpg)

Linking to either (www.website.com/client/images/logo.jpg) links to naught. Neither do longer variations like (www.website.com/client/system/expressionengine/templates/default_site/site.group/images/logo.jpg)

Halp.

Answer (score 1):

Template groups are not meant to hold that kind of static content, `/templates`  is not public (at our install it is even outisde of `www`).

You need to change your upload folder to `/client/themes/uploads` or something similar, then you can access your uploads as `{path=themes/uploads}/image_name.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

try using the path: /images/logo.jpg or /client/images/logo.jpg

Also, direct those questions to http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewforum/113/

you'll receive help from a larger pool of knowledgeable users.